# How to download text version of website?

Tags: http, telnet

How can I download the text version of a website? I need to do that using http raw protocol, e.g. telnet. However, I have no idea. Any hint?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the server still supports the original HTTP protocol version

```
telnet www.example.com 80 | tee page.txt
get /index.html
```

If the server manages several sites you'll need to preceed the request with a host header.

For more recent versions of HTTP you'll need to do some other stuff. The RFCs are a useful resource.